# Webmatrix - WebGrid: change css style conditionally

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix, webgrid

I've just started with Webmatrix and I'm trying to transform an HTML table to the webgrid.
The data comes from the DB and I want to change the css class for each td (within one column) depending on the items content.

So for example if the item Contains "," then apply class="multi", if it doesn't contain "," and is not null then class="single", else "none".

```
<td class="multi">
<td class="single">
<td class="none">
```

I've tried it with the webgrid **style:** and **format:** settings but I couldn't get the classname to switch depending on the value of the item. I think I just need the right syntax to get started.

I hope you can help me out here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the WebGrid, your only real option is to set the `td` style based on the cell value via Javascript after it has rendered. The `style` parameter will only accept a string representing the CSS class to apply.

Alternatively, you can conditionally set the content in the `format` parameter based on the value, filling the `td` with a `span` or `div` that you can then style eg:

```
<style>
    td.nopadding{padding: 0;margin: 0;}
    .green{background-color:green;display: inline-block;width: 100%;height: 100%;}
    .yellow{background-color:yellow;display: inline-block;width: 100%;height: 100%;}
</style>
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(    
        tableStyle : "table",
        alternatingRowStyle : "alternate",
        headerStyle : "header",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Country", style: "nopadding", format: @<text>@Html.Raw(item.Country == "USA" ? 
                                                                 "<span class=\"green\">" + item.Country +"</span>" : 
                                                                 "<span class=\"yellow\">" + item.Country +"</span>")</text>))
    )
</div>
```

UPDATE: The following code illustrates a more complex if..else statement being accommodated in the format parameter:

```
format: @<text>@if(item.YourProperty == null){
                  @Html.Raw("<span class=\"none\">" + some_value +"</span>")
                  }
                  else{
                    if(item.YourProperty.Contains(",")){
                         @Html.Raw("<span class=\"multi\">" + some_value +"</span>")
                    }
                    else{
                        @Html.Raw("<span class=\"single\">" + some_value +"</span>")
                    }
               }
               </text>
```

Comment: thank you for the code example - however I can't get it to work. I have to use some method like Contains() but I don't know how to use it in razor.

Comment: Actually, the code part is standard C#, so you apply it as usual. I have updated my reply to include a sample of code that shows how your logic might be accommodated. It will need tweaking as I don't know your item's property names or what you actually want to do with the css styles.